# Unable to add password field in balance transfer example in hyperledger fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Actually i want to add password field in balance transfer example but i am getting unhandled rejection error in json. please anyone resolve the issue.

> curl -s -X POST \   http://localhost:4000/users \   -H "content-type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \   -d
>   'username=Jim&orgName=org1&password=Subbu@123'

Comment: curl -s -X POST \
  http://localhost:4000/users \
  -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  -d 'username=Jim&orgName=org1&password=Subbu@123'